# Reading data from Arduino in Matlab through serial port

Tags: matlab, arduino

Hi guys I am new to matlab. I would like to read data output from arduino through serial port. The data is output at certain time interval with comma/ space separating the variables. How I read the data and plot the variable on Matlab?

The serial port is like this:

1.1 3.2

1.2 3.1

1.3 3.3
...

Thanks for your help.

---

This is the code I got for reading data of only one variable without any space. How to modify that to read data of more than one variable?

```
close all; 
clear all;
clc; 
fclose('all'); 
delete(instrfindall);

%User Defined Properties 
s = serial('COM5', 'baudrate', 9600);
plotTitle='HCSR04';
xLabel='Time (s)';
yLabel='Distance (cm)';
plotGrid = 'on';                
delay = .01;

%Define Function Variables
time = 0;
distance = 0;
count = 0;

%Set up Plot
plotGraph = plot(time,distance);             
title(plotTitle,'FontSize',25);
xlabel(xLabel,'FontSize',15);
ylabel(yLabel,'FontSize',15);
grid(plotGrid);

fopen(s);
tic

while ishandle(plotGraph)
        dist = str2num(fscanf(s))
        count = count + 1;    
        time(count) = toc;
        distance(count) = dist;
        set(plotGraph,'XData',time,'YData',distance);
        axis([time(count)-10 time(count) 0 10]);
        pause(delay);
end
fclose(s);
clear all;
close all;
```

---

I tried this one but seems not working.

```
close all; 
clear all;
clc; 
fclose('all'); 
delete(instrfindall);

%User Defined Properties 
s = serial('COM3', 'baudrate', 9600);
plotTitle='Sensor Test';
xLabel='Time (s)';
yLabel='Distance (cm)';
plotGrid = 'on';                
delay = .01;

%Define Function Variables
time = 0;
distance1 = 0;
distance2 = 0;
count = 0;

%Set up Plot
plotGraph(1) = plot(time,distance1);
plotGraph(2) = plot(time,distance2);
title(plotTitle,'FontSize',25);
xlabel(xLabel,'FontSize',15);
ylabel(yLabel,'FontSize',15);
grid(plotGrid);

fopen(s);
tic

while ishandle(plotGraph)
        str = fscanf(s);
        dist = textscan(str,'%f %f');
        count = count + 1;    
        time(count) = toc;
        dist1(count) = dist(1);
        dist2(count) = dist(2);
        set(plotGraph(1),'XData',time,'YData',dist1);
        set(plotGraph(2),'XData',time,'YData',dist2); 
        axis([time(count)-10 time(count) 0 10]);
        pause(delay);
end
fclose(s);
clear all;
close all;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the point where you get the data from your arduino. This line in your code:

```
dist = str2num(fscanf(s))
```

There it gets the data from your serial object `s`. You could change it into this:

```
str = fscanf(s);
dist = textscan(str,'%f %f');
```

Now you have `dist` as a variable with two numbers in it. To put them in two seperate variables you could do this:

```
distance1(count) = dist(1);
distance2(count) = dist(2);
```

To put them into your plot you now require two lines, so your distance variable starts as

```
distance = [0 0];
```

And to put them in your graph you use

```
set(plotGraph(1),'XData',time,'YData',distance1);
set(plotGraph(2),'XData',time,'YData',distance2);
```

Comment: I received the following error:str =

    '5.20 5.18
     '

Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in VL53L0X (line 33)
        distance1(count) = dist(1);

Comment: Read the error. It says your index is not a real positive integer. You start count at 0, then you must first increase by 1 before you use it as an index. Move this line up two lines `count = count + 1;` You're new to Matlab. It has one-based indexing. This can be a bit confusing.

Comment: Still didn't work...no error but no graph appeared. I am so bad in programming...

Comment: Strange. Maybe replace `plotGraph(1) = plot(time,distance1);plotGraph(2) = plot(time,distance2);` with `plotGraph=plot(time,[distance1,distance2]);`